# Getting the Windows kernel version in Java?

Tags: java

I want to get the kernel version in Windows using Java. Is there any class in Java to get the info?

I am able to find the OS name using `System.getProperty("os.name");`, but I want the kernel version instead.

Comment: can i ask you, why it is required ?

Answer (score 3):

With the **ver** command you can get a more precise kernel version (if needed)

You can execute it using cmd and then parse it

```
  final String dosCommand = "cmd /c ver";
      final String location = "C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32";
      try {
         final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            dosCommand + " " + location);
         final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
         int ch;
         while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)ch);
         }
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Result (example)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try :

```
System.getProperty("os.version");
```

If you want to check the same on Linux or Android you can do so by this statement:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uname -r");
```

Comment: with os.version it is giving 6.1 as output. but i am not sure if windows version is same as the kernel version.

Comment: but i need it in Windows...i found few links for Linux or Android but for Windows.